# The Hasse invariant at cuspidal elliptic curves in a generically ordinary family

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, positive-characteristic

For an elliptic curve of the form $y^2 = f(x)$ where $f(x) \in \mathbb F_q[x]$ is a cubic polynomial with distinct roots, it is known (from Silverman's book, say) that the curve is supersingular precisely when the coefficient of $x^{p-1}$ in $f(x)^\frac{p-1}{2}$ is $0$.

My question is about the behavior of this coefficient in families of curves. Consider the following families of elliptic curves in characteristic $p>3$.

1. $E_1:y^2 = f_1(x,t) =  x(x-1)(x-t)$ and
2. $E_2:y^2 = f_2(x,t) = x^3+3tx^2+3x+1$

where we can think of $t$ as an element of $\overline{\mathbb F}_q[t]$. We can plug in any value $\alpha$ from $\overline {\mathbb F}_q$ for $t$ and so long $f_i(x,\alpha)$ doesn't obtain roots with multiplicity $>1$, we still get an elliptic curve. The key difference between the above two families is that the former has node at $t=0,1$ and the latter has a cusp singularity at $t=1$.

Now I want to study the $x^{p-1}$ coefficient of $f_i(x,t)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ as an element of $\overline{\mathbb F}_q[t]$. Let us call it $H_i(t)$. Now, by doing some experiments in [Sage (you can play around with these equations in the link)](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrULBVsDTn5XID0u5uGgWa1gqOejYldkCuW3SsdZCeTYWdrWN0LC9Xmm1FnLG2sVaJVkWcEZCu0Dbk5Uq2zcksLtFIi9PQKNA11NQ30tS05uUqKMrMK9EAyyRHA8Vj9dISk0vyizQ0NTUBQY4eBg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), I have seen that $H_1(t)$ does not vanish at $t=0,1$ (and can prove it using an old argument of Igusa) but $H_2(t)$ **does** seem to vanish at $t=1$ with a very large and predictable multiplicity: $\frac{p-1}{6}$ if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6$ and $\frac{p+1}{6}$ if $p\equiv 5 \pmod 6$.

My question is why does this happen? So I've managed to tweak the equation of $E_2$ a bit so that the curve retains it's cusp but makes bookkeeping easier and have found a combinatorial proof of this high order vanishing. But I am looking for something more geometric that explains it. Somehow the polynomial vanishes on $\mathbb G_a$ but not on $\mathbb G_m$? This feels very much like the mod-$p$ modular form that goes by the name of the Hasse invariant or at least it's pullback under the map to the moduli space of elliptic curves. Is $\mathbb G_a$ "very supersingular" while $\mathbb G_m$ is "ordinary" under a suitable interpretation? Can someone give an explanation or direct me to a book/paper on what is going on and what the relationship of this polynomial is to the different types of singularities?

NB: This phenomenon is clearly not unique to Elliptic Curves: Even for some higher genus cases, I see very similar patterns happening: If there are cusps or higher order singularities for a curve in a family of curves $C_t$ at a point $a$, this large order of vanishing at $a$ is happening for an appropriate analog of the coefficient studied above.

Comment: I think this would be a fine question to ask on MO if you don't get answers here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was hoping to hear from you! :)
You're absolutely right, as usual! I will update it now, thank you.

Comment: You are too kind. Unless a miracle occurs, your question is above my paygrade :-)